# In this sentence why is 'the' omitted?

Tags: grammar, definite-article

> 1. We shall start tomorrow, *if the weather* permits.
> 2. We shall start tomorrow, *weather* permitting.

Both sentences are equal. Rather, I think *We shall start tomorrow, the weather permitting*.

In the second sentence, why has '**the**' been omitted?

Comment: The set phrase "weather permitting" is an absolute construction meaning if the weather permits.

Comment: Weather refers to the state of atmosphere, and is not ambiguous as other nouns such as "writer" or "reader" might be, in which case they can refer to different subjects. As such, omitting "the" does not deprive the sentence of clarity and it sounds fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, both sentences are equal; your

> We shall start tomorrow, the weather permitting.

May be acceptable in certain locales, but at least it the western US it sounds odd.  However, it is still easily understood.