# When is "the" omitted?

Tags: grammar, articles, error

Here is a paragraph [from today's Wall Street Journal](http://www.wsj.com/articles/twin-bombs-rattle-shoppers-in-bangkok-1422838378).

> Some businesses in the area closed their doors while authorities briefly closed an elevated train station **outside mall** where the improvised explosive devices, or IEDs, had been placed.

I wonder why it is "outside mall", not "outside the mall". Why is "the" omitted?

If you need more context than this paragraph, please visit the link!

Comment: Probably whoever wrote this made a mistake. Since you give us no source, I assume _you_ wrote it. Why do you ask us why _you_ left out the article? If it is not your own text, please provide us with the source!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about explaining something based on the assumed correctness of a  simple mistake in a text of unknown origin.

Comment: @oerkelens It's from today's Wall Street Journal. It constitutes an entire paragraph from the article. Have added the link. PS, if a user has 101 points, it's probably there first ever question here! :-)

Comment: It is the first time I wrote at Stackexchange. So I didn't know that I should provide the sources. It is a part of an article from WSJ. That's why I assumed this sentence is quite ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's a mistake. It should be **outside the mall**, just as you thought. The sentence is indicating specifically *which* mall was near the train station: **the** mall where the IEDs had been placed, which is also **the** mall that was mentioned at the start of the article.

Comment: Thank you! Is there some occasions when "the" can be omitted? For example, I found this question and answer: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32895/in-this-sentence-why-is-the-omitted?rq=1 It says that "weather" can be used without "a" or "the". Is it correct?

Comment: +1. I would go so far as to say there is a 100% chance this is a typographical error. It's not the sort of error a native speaker would make in speech.

Comment: @hjjang Articles in English are a pretty complex topic, probably requiring [many questions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles?sort=votes), which could take a lifetime to answer. Seriously! But here are three fundamental things to know: (1) Every noun _must_ have a [determiner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner). (2) Omitting an article is still a sort of article—it _means_ something. (3) Special phrases can override everything: ***X* permitting** is one such phrase. That's why **weather** lacks an article in that question.

Comment: There is not room to list how many ways "the" can properly be eliminated. Look for questions with "the", or for "article elision" here or elsewhere.